# Pycharm Cannot find reference 'linspace' in matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pycharm

I'm trying to plot a graph in my pycharm ide using the matplotlib library. But I am unable to do so. Because Pycharm shows me this message : Cannot find reference 'linspace' in '**init**.pyi | **init**.pyi'
Here's my code =

```
x=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a=np.array(x)
print(a)
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y= x ** 2
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does the code execute?

Comment: i think this code is correct but you should add this line of code in the end to show the plot    plt.show()

Comment: When does this occure?  on the import, or the plt?

Comment: This is not an error message - it's a linter warning.

Comment: I have the same issue. Yes, the code runs correctly, and no, this is not a linter warning. It's PyCharm unable to find `linespace` method, while in fact it is defined in `numpy/core/function_base.py`.

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue that occurred after `numpy` devs switched approach to exposing public stubs in version `1.20`. The re-imports in `numpy/__init__.pyi` were left without `as` keyword, which made them private. Those imports were instead added to `__all__`, but PyCharm wasn't supporting this approach.

It was fixed in PyCharm 2020.3.3. So after you upgrade the message will be gone, and the reference method will be available.

Comment: The issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-46169

Answer (score -1):

i think this code is correct but you should add this line of code in the end to show the plot

```
x=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a=np.array(x)
print(a)
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
print(x)
y= x ** 2
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: How would that relate to the error message `Cannot find reference 'linspace' in 'init.pyi | init.pyi' `?